# CodeIgniter turn off automatic routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to turn off the automatic routing in CodeIgniter and have it only process requests if a route for that request exists? Thanks.

Comment: Codeigniter does not have `automatic` routing as such. If you have a controller called `shop` and an action called `cart`, you have a route of `/shop/cart`. If you want to create a route for `shopping-cart` then you simply only link to `shopping-cart` and not `/shop/cart`. This way, there is very little chance that anyone will know that `/shop/cart` exists.

Answer (score 10):

Keep in mind that Dale's solution:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "some/default/controller/$1";
```

only works for one-segment URLs, like:

```
example.com/foo
```

but not for:

```
example.com/foo/bar
```

**You can get around this by using a regular expression instead of the CI wildcard. And by routing to a non-existing class drops a show_404() indeed:**

```
$route['(.*)'] = "none";
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can't turn off CI's automatic routing, but there is a work around:

```
// you specific routes
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['search/(:any)'] = "search/$1";
// the catch all route
$route['(:any)'] = "some/default/controller/$1";
```

Which doesn't actually turn off CI's routing but routes all unmatched uri's to the default controller.

Alternatively you could route to a non-existent controller which I believe will throw the in built 404 error

Comment: I think he is worried about duplicate content not about unmatched uri's

Comment: More importantly, you have the `404_override` route for this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, another solution could be extends the `Router`.

1. Create a class name MY_Route at /application/core/MY_Router declared as `class MY_Router extends CI_Router`.
2. You could override the method `_set_routing()`:

   > This function determines what should be served based on the URI request, as well as any "routes" that have been set in the routing config file.

It should be more complex, but at least can guide you to another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 4 solution: 
app/config/Routes.php at line 24 set value true to false

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since CodeIgniter v4.2.0, the auto-routing is [disabled by default](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=autorouting#use-defined-routes-only:%7E:text=%EF%83%81-,Since%20v4.2.0%2C%20the%20auto%2Drouting%20is%20disabled%20by%20default.,-When%20no%20defined).

You can disable the automatic matching, and **restrict routes to only those defined by you**, by setting the `$autoRoute` property to false:

```
<?php

// In app/Config/Routing.php
class Routing extends BaseRouting
{
    // ...
    public bool $autoRoute = false;
    // ...
}

// This can be overridden in the Routes file
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
```

More info on the CI docs:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=autorouting#use-defined-routes-only

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible turn off the automatic routing convention in CodeIgniter as far as I know, but you can put entries in your .htaccess file to redirect de default routes to the routes you've created.